# Showing a generic image when no image is chosen

Tags: templating

I'm trying to do this:

```
{% for image in entry.illustration %}
    {% if image | length %}
        <a href="{{ entry.url }}" class="flag__img">
            <img src="{{ image.getUrl }}" alt="{{ entry.altText }}" class="profile__image">
        </a>
    {% else %}  
        <p>No image.</p>        
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Without any luck. What would be a good way of telling craft to do something else if entry.illustration does not have an image defined?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try this:

```
{% for image in entry.illustration %}
  {% if image %}
      <a href="{{ entry.url }}" class="flag__img"><img src="{{ image.getUrl() }}" alt="{{ entry.altText }}" class="profile__image" /></a>
  {% else %}
    <p>No image.</p>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

(Assuming the altText field is an entry field.) :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make it a little smaller, you could use a ternary statement, so on your img tag, you could use the following

```
<img src="{{ image ? image.getUrl : 'http://example.com/image.png' }}" />
```

So you're full snippet would be

```
{% for image in entry.illustration %}
        <a href="{{ entry.url }}" class="flag__img">
            <img src="{{ image ? image.getUrl : 'http://example.com/image.png' }}" alt="{{ image.altText ? image.altText : "Default Alt Text" }}" class="profile__image" />

        </a>
{% endfor %}
```

A ternary statement is basically a shorthand if statement.

```
{{ (condition is true) ? do this : else do this }}
```

Also changed `entry.altText` to `image.altText` in the for loop. That may be where you are going wrong?

Comment: Thanks. Could you be a bit more specific please? This didn't do much good.

Comment: edited the above to help you out.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I now have this, but it still doesn't output the placehold.it image: {% for image in employee.illustration %}
        <a href="{{ employee.url }}" class="flag__img">
            <img src="{{ image ? image.getUrl : 'http://placehold.it/60x30' }}" alt="{{ image.altText ? image.altText : "Default Alt Text" }}" class="profile__circular" />
        </a>
{% endfor %}

Comment: try http:// before it ?

Comment: It actually has http:// before it, just not when I paste the code in here :)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that *illustration* is an asset field, and you want to display all the images, or *No image* if there are none. You can do that with an `else` clause on the `for`.

```
{% for image in entry.illustration %}
  <a href="{{ entry.url }}" class="flag__img">
    <img src="{{ image.getUrl }}" alt="{{ entry.altText }}" class="profile__image">
  </a>
{% else %}
  <p>No image.</p>        
{% endfor %}
```